# get extension of file without knowing the extension, no patterns

Tags: r, file

How I can get the extension of a file? Are there any function or tool package in R for this?

for example, if I have a file as "file.txt", how get the extension?. I want to get the extension without having to know, I can not use functions that use patterns.

thank you very much

Comment: Why can't you use regular expressions? (assuming that's what you mean by "patterns")? Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `file_ext`

```
> file_ext("test.exe")
[1] "exe"
```

As a side note, you don't need a separate package for file I/O tasks, just have a look in package base to the set of functions dealing with files. Some are:

1. `file`
2. `file.access`
3. `file.exists`
4. `file.info`

and many many others. A cool one is `basename` which extract the file name from a path

Comment: thank you very much, did not know that there was this function, you saved my life!

Comment: @Alex glad that it helped. You can accept the answer now ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone wants the regex,

```
foo<- 'file.ext'

gsub('^.*[.]','',foo)
# 'ext'
```

Edit: to catch all kinds of filenames,

```
foo<-'file.something.zip.ext'
regmatches(foo,regexpr('[^.]*$',foo)  )
```

(probably a shorter way to do that, but left as an exercise to the reader :-) )

Answer (score 1):

```
filenames <- c("file.txt", "file.csv")
sapply(strsplit(filenames, ".", fixed=TRUE), tail, n=1L)
#[1] "txt" "csv"
```